# CSS: Height Property

Tags: html, css

after a long session of trial and error with my css stylesheet, and a even longer websearch that didn't help I decided to post my problem here and hope, that somebody can help me.

The problem: I try to build a website with fixed header, footer and navigation bar on the side. When I set the height property of the complete html body to 100 percent (or to 100vh) and then the height of the header to 15 percent, of the footer to 5 percent and of the content to 80 percent, then the height of the content section is way to big. Maybe I don't understand this property well, because I'm not so familiar with css, but I think it should work.

Here is my code:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #2F4F4F;
  background-color: #FFEBCD;
  font-family: 'Baloo Thambi', cursive;
}
header {
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed !important;
  position: absolute;
  height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #DC143C;
}
header img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 5%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #FF7F50;
}
#Content {
  top: 15%;
  height: 65%;
  left: 20%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 5%;
}
#Buttons {
  left: 0px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
#Side-Nav {
  margin-top: 10%;
}
footer {
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2F4F4F;
  color: #F0F8FF;
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.button1 {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 5%;
}
.button1:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #2F4F4F;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CL - Craft</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
  initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v2" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Thambi" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/img/manifest.json">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="/img/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/img/browserconfig.xml">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="img/header.png">
    </a>
  </header>
  <nav>
    </br>
    Navigation:
    <section id="Side-Nav">
      <a href="aktuelles.html" class="button1">Aktuelles</a>
      <a href="karte.html" class="button1">Karte</a>
      <a href="hilfe.html" class="button1">Info's</a>
      <a href="downloads.html" class="button1">Downloads</a> 
    </section>

  </nav>
  <section id="Content">
    <h1>Karte</h1>
    <iframe src="http://www.cl-craft.de:8123" width="100%" height="100%">
    </iframe>
    </br>
    </br>



    <section id="Buttons">
      <a href="aktuelles.html" class="button">Aktuelles</a>
      <a href="karte.html" class="button">Karte</a>
      <a href="hilfe.html" class="button">Info's</a>
      <a href="downloads.html" class="button">Downloads</a>
    </section>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <?php include( "serverstatus.php"); ?>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Can somebody explain, what is the mistake in this stylesheet?

Comment: Share your html codes

Comment: we need some HTML

Comment: And what is "way too big"? How high is your window in pixels and how high does the content section end up as? Use your browsers' inspect tools, that's what they're there for.

Comment: I added a html code, there you can see the problem. I want that the content section is scrollable. At the moment I can scroll the section and header, footer and navbar is fixed. But the content section is too big, so the bottem of the scrollbar is out of the window. I want that the bottom of the scollbar is adjacent to the footer. And somehow it doesnt works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you've built your layout by absolutely positioning all of your elements. Instead, you should use flexbox or something like a bootstrap grid. Because everything is absolutely positioned, it won't be able to dynamically adjust to screen sizes. You can fix the scrollbar problem with some tweaks to padding and z-index, but that will only fix it on whatever device you're looking at right now. As soon as you open it on another screen resolution everything will break.

Check out http://getbootstrap.com/ - it should be relatively simple to implement it in the code you've posted above.

Additionally, if you want to level up your css skills you can try this great flexbox course for free - http://flexbox.io/

Comment: That's not the complete answer, is it. Absolute positioning doesn't mean that styles don't work. If a parent has a height of 100% and the child has 65%, then that's how high the child is, absolutely positioned or not.